# Assign values to Angular-ui modal

Tags: angularjs, forms, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I think i have some pretty big holes in my code, as when the modal is appearing, the content from the table (which when you click on a row produces the modal), is not populating the input boxes I have inside of the modal. I think I'm tackling the situation in the wrong way and some direction would be fantastic.

My JS:

```
var app = angular.module('peopleInformation', ['ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http, $uibModal) {

$http.get("Assignment005.json").success(function(response){
    $scope.myData = response.People;
});

$scope.modify = function(currentData){

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller:function($scope, $uibModalInstance, details){
                $scope.FirstName = details.FirstName;
                $scope.LastName = details.LastName;
                $scope.Age = details.Age;
                $scope.Nickname = details.Nickname;

            $scope.update = function () {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            };
        },
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
            details: function() {
                return currentData;
            }
        }   
    });

};
});
```

My modal:

```
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Your row of data</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" name="modelData" style="height:200px">
                  <form class="form-horizontal pull-left form-width" role="form">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="first">First Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first" ng-model="FirstName">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="last">Last Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last" ng-model="LastName">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="age">Age:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="age" ng-model="Age">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="nick">Nickname:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8"> 
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nick" ng-model="Nickname">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Main HTML in case it's needed:

```
<body>
<div data-ng-app="peopleInformation" data-ng-controller="myCtrl" class="jumbotron">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Essential Information</div>
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Nickname</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr data-ng-repeat="details in myData" data-ng-click="modify(details)">
                        <td>{{ details.FirstName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ details.LastName }}</td>
                        <td>{{ details.Age }}</td>
                        <td>{{ details.Nickname }}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>                    
              </table>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right" data-ng-click="new()">Add
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
  <div ng-include="myModalContent.html"></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Im very new to using Angular so if you could be overtly simple with me that would help to clarify things, although again, any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is `modify` called?

Comment: In my main html (its bulky so I didn't post it, but here is the call).
It's attached to each row of my table so when you click the table row, the modal appears and the fields should be populated.
"data-ng-click="modify(details)"

Answer (score 1):

Bellow is the angular modal instance controller

```
 app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope,
 $uibModalInstance, item) {

   $scope.customer = item;

   $scope.yes = function () {
     $uibModalInstance.close();   };

   $scope.no = function () {
     $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');   
  }; 
});
```

bellow is the code for call angular modal

```
 $scope.open = function (item) {
     var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
       animation: true,
       scope: $scope,
       templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
       controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
       size: 'md',
       resolve: {
         item: function () {
          return item;
         }
       }
     });

     modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $log.info(selectedItem);
       });
     }, function () {
       $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
     });   
   };
```

Bellow is code for template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Re-calculate retail price</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        Margin percent of selected customer is <b>{{ customer.margin_percent }}</b> <br />
        Do you want to recalculate the retail price?
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="yes()">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="no()">No</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: The template and the AngularJS modal / modal instance controller don't match up? However I have recently got mine working now, thank you for the answer!

Comment: templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html', controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl', are responsible for match up between template and modal instance

Comment: Thanks @Callum for edit. I think you don't need to pass $scope to modal, because there are separate scope for modal controller. You just to pass required parameters to to modal instance

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file you are passing different parameter to modify function, It should be equal to the parameter specified in ng-repeat directive.
So in this case this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="data in myData" data-ng-click="modify(details)">
```

will become:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="details in myData" data-ng-click="modify(details)">
```

Comment: This produces an error, you need the function call so it know where to go to return the data I believe.

Comment: Again, this my fault for posting old code, I actually fixed the above problem but forgot to update, I will do so now, however I do think I've solved my own problem as per my answer below, thank you very much for helping though, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually assigning the values in the wrong place I believe. I moved the:

```
$scope.FirstName = details.FirstName;
```

Outside of the `var modalInstance` variable, and they are now populating the input boxes. If this is messy or not standard then let me know as sometimes the right result is not always the right method. Thanks for those that tried to help, much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to pass scope to your modal instance to make it work.

Comment: $scope is passed into the modal instance inside of the controller.
see: 

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller:function($scope, $uibModalInstance, details)

Comment: I am not talking about that scope. add a parameter in modal instance parameters like: scope: $scope,